Plotting (discontinuous) 2d-functions correctly with d3
I have to have a smooth plot of a decisionboundary which is a function that takes (x,y) as input and returns a single value. The decisionboundary points that I have to plot have to be smaller than a certain threshold (near zero).
But the approaches that I tried are not satisfying.

My first approach was evaluating the whole grid and filter but this is compuationally expensive if I want the appearance of a smooth curve:

if (!dataPoints.some((point) => point.t === 1) || !dataPoints.some((point) => point.t === -1)) return;
  
    const X = dataPoints.map((d) => generateBasisFunctions(d.x, d.y, polyDegree));
    const t = dataPoints.map((d) => (d.t === 1 ? 1 : 0));
  
    let weights = new Array(X[0].length).fill(0);
  
    const maxIterations = 10;
    const tolerance = 1e-5;
  
    for (let iter = 0; iter < maxIterations; iter++) {
      const predictions = X.map((x) => sigmoid(numeric.dot(x, weights)));
      const errors = numeric.sub(predictions, t);
  
      const R = numeric.diag(predictions.map((p) => p * (1 - p)));
      const Hessian = numeric.dot(numeric.dot(numeric.transpose(X), R), X);
      const gradient = numeric.dot(numeric.transpose(X), errors);
  
      const update = numeric.solve(Hessian, gradient);
      weights = numeric.sub(weights, update);
  
      if (numeric.norm2(update) < tolerance) {
        console.log("iterations", iter);
        break;
      }
    }
  
    // Plotting
    const decisionBoundary = (x, y) => {
      const phi = generateBasisFunctions(x, y, polyDegree);
      return numeric.dot(phi, weights);
    };
  
    const boundaryPoints = [];
    const stepSize = 0.0025; 
  
    for (let x = -1; x <= 1; x += stepSize) {
      for (let y = -1; y <= 1; y += stepSize) {
        if (Math.abs(decisionBoundary(x, y)) < 0.125) {
          boundaryPoints.push({ x, y });
        }
      }
    }
  
    if (decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current) decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current.remove();
    decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current = coordinateSystemRef.current
      .selectAll(".lst-db-activated-polynomial-basis-function")
      .data(boundaryPoints)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "lst-db-activated-polynomial-basis-function")
      .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.x))
      .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.y))
      .attr("height", 4)
      .attr("width", 4);



My second approach was using contours but just isnt a good representation of the decisioboundary:

    // Plotting
    const decisionBoundary = (x, y) => {
      const phi = generateBasisFunctions(x, y, polyDegree);
      return numeric.dot(phi, weights);
    };

    const n = 100;
    const boundaryData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        const x = -1 + (i * 2) / n;
        const y = -1 + (j * 2) / n;
        boundaryData.push([x, y, decisionBoundary(x, y)]);
      }
    }

    const contours = d3.contourDensity()
      .x(d => xScale(d[0]))
      .y(d => yScale(d[1]))
      .size([width, height])
      .thresholds(50)
      .bandwidth(100)
      (boundaryData.filter(d => Math.abs(d[2]) < 0.1));

    if (decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current) decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current.remove();
    decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current = coordinateSystemRef.current
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "lst-db-activated-polynomial-basis-function")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(contours)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.geoPath())
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5); 



And using standard paths which are then interpolated by d3 results always in a curve which connects to the nearest points according to the x-coordinate


    // Plotting
    const decisionBoundary = (x, y) => {
      const phi = generateBasisFunctions(x, y, polyDegree);
      return numeric.dot(phi, weights);
    };

    const boundaryPoints = [];
    const stepSize = 0.0025;

    for (let x = -1; x <= 1; x += stepSize) {
      for (let y = -1; y <= 1; y += stepSize) {
        if (Math.abs(decisionBoundary(x, y)) < 0.125) {
          boundaryPoints.push({ x, y });
        }
      }
    }

    const lineGenerator = d3
      .line()
      .x((d) => xScale(d.x))
      .y((d) => yScale(d.y));

    if (decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current) decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current.remove();
    decisionBoundaryActivatedRef.current = coordinateSystemRef.current
      .selectAll(".lst-db-activated-polynomial-basis-function")
      .data([boundaryPoints])
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "lst-db-activated-polynomial-basis-function")
      .attr("d", lineGenerator);

How to properly plot in such scenarios where you have discontinuous functions where a path would fail to capture the function?
